# What is the method to add a payment and a subscription in my apple and android app?

Tags: android, xcode, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I'm developing an app in which a professional creates an account to display his informations and user can access to this app and see the informations of the professional.
To obtain an account, the professional have to pay first a unique payment for the first twelve months and after he will pay for a subscription.

My questions :

```
- do I have to use the apple and google payment system ? (apple in-app purchase and google in-app purchase) ?

- what are the differences between google in-app purchase and google in-app billing ?

- can I use another purchase system like Braintree ?

- If not, with apple and google system, can the professional use only his credit card without any google pay or apple pay account ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With iOS apps, you have to use Apple Pay to facilitate the payment. You'd have to use this (https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/)

Use of Braintree may be possible with the Android ecosystem. Check out https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/braintree-android-pay/

Differences;
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/earn/in-app-purchases
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing

Basically Play Billing is for a one-off purchase or subscription-based items. You'd usually use this when you're buying app subscription or paid apps.

In ap is more relevant for games, that unlock features based on purchases.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it possible to start with a free app (in apple and android) and add a payment method later ? you will say I can add the payment method and add a free trial but it will take too many time and I would like to have first return from real people as soon as possible. It will give me time to add payment method